# Populating a created column with values obtained by comparison

Tags: r, dax

Suppose I have two tables:

```
tableOne <- data.frame(date = c("2022-01-14", "2022-03-15", "2022-05-20", "2022-06-02", "2022-08-21"),
                       eqmt = c("EQ01","EQ02","EQ02","EQ01","EQ02"),
                       values = c( 18,20, 24, 25, 27)
                       )
```

and

```
tableTwo <- data.frame( `Read Date` =c("2022-03-27", "2022-04-10", "2022-02-05","2022-07-19", "2022-08-20"),
                        Plant = c("EQ02", "EQ02", "EQ01", "EQ01","EQ02"),
                        Reading = c(205, 215, 370, 420, 260)
                        )
```

I would like code that will look at the entries in the `eqmt` column, find the rows in `tableTwo` that have the corresponding value (e.g, when the code is at Row 1 in `tableOne`, it should identify rows 3 & 4 in `tableTwo` as having the entry EQ01 in the `plant` column), compare the `date` and `Read Date` entries and return, per row in a new column in `tableOne`, `Read Date`values greater than `date` in the given row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this will answer your question:

```
tableOne %>%
  left_join(tableTwo, by = c("eqmt" = "Plant")) %>%
  filter( as.Date(Read.Date) > as.Date(date) )

        date eqmt values  Read.Date Reading
1 2022-01-14 EQ01     18 2022-02-05     370
2 2022-01-14 EQ01     18 2022-07-19     420
3 2022-03-15 EQ02     20 2022-03-27     205
4 2022-03-15 EQ02     20 2022-04-10     215
5 2022-03-15 EQ02     20 2022-08-20     260
6 2022-05-20 EQ02     24 2022-08-20     260
7 2022-06-02 EQ01     25 2022-07-19     420
```

However, as there are multiple matches where Read.Date is larger than date, you will end up with more rows than initially.

Comment: Thanks for this option, this one seems to work really well for this case I presented. Just out of curiosity, do you perceive there is a loop solution to this question?

Comment: I dont see a viable option to solve this using a loop, since there is no real need to use iteration here. The Problem you statet is best solved using one of the many join options.

Comment: I see, thanks very much. Yes, the join options presented here solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be to try the `fuzzyjoin` package. You can provide the two data.frames, indicate what columns to join on, and the `match_fun` to indicate functions of equality for comparison.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_inner_join(
  tableOne,
  tableTwo,
  by = c("eqmt" = "Plant", "date" = "Read.Date"),
  match_fun = c(`==`, `<`)
)
```

**Output**

```
        date eqmt values  Read.Date Plant Reading
1 2022-01-14 EQ01     18 2022-02-05  EQ01     370
2 2022-01-14 EQ01     18 2022-07-19  EQ01     420
3 2022-03-15 EQ02     20 2022-03-27  EQ02     205
4 2022-03-15 EQ02     20 2022-04-10  EQ02     215
5 2022-03-15 EQ02     20 2022-08-20  EQ02     260
6 2022-05-20 EQ02     24 2022-08-20  EQ02     260
7 2022-06-02 EQ01     25 2022-07-19  EQ01     420
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use {powerjoin}:

```r
library(powerjoin)

power_inner_join(
  tableOne,
  tableTwo,
  by = c(eqmt = "Plant", ~ .x$date < .y$Read.Date)
)
#>         date eqmt values  Read.Date Reading
#> 1 2022-01-14 EQ01     18 2022-02-05     370
#> 2 2022-01-14 EQ01     18 2022-07-19     420
#> 3 2022-03-15 EQ02     20 2022-03-27     205
#> 4 2022-03-15 EQ02     20 2022-04-10     215
#> 5 2022-03-15 EQ02     20 2022-08-20     260
#> 6 2022-05-20 EQ02     24 2022-08-20     260
#> 7 2022-06-02 EQ01     25 2022-07-19     420
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>